# Trouble getting Jasmine to test routing (iron:router related)

Tags: jasmine, iron-router, meteor-velocity

I've just started trying to use velocity testing for Meteor. I've hit a roadblock trying to put my routes under test. I can't get this to work with Jasmine or Mocha:

(With only the packages iron:router, velocity:html-reporter, coffeescript and sanjo-jasmine added to a default meteor app.)
In /tests/jasmine/client/integration/router-test.coffee:

```
describe "Route", ->
    describe "non-existing", ->
        it "should not run green", ->
            Router.go "foo"
            expect(Router.current().url).toEqual("/foo")
    describe "existing", ->
        it "should run green", ->
            Router.go "bar"
            expect(Router.current().url).toEqual("/bar")
```

In /client/router.coffee:

```
Router.route "bar"
```

And in the default html file:

```
<template name="bar">
    <p>Yeah.</p>
</template>
```

If I run `Router.go("bar")` in the JS console, it works fine as expected: `Router.current().url` outputs `/bar`. However, in the reporter I get the following error:

```
Expected 'http://localhost:64927/?jasmine=true' to equal '/bar'.
```

Which implies that the router does indeed find the route "bar", but the navigation seems to not run in the same way. Even stranger, when I navigate to `http://localhost:64927/?jasmine=true`, my browser jumps to `http://localhost:64927/bar` by some magic means.

Any ideas?

Also, I've noticed that sometimes tests run green, despite there being an uncaught exception on the JS console. Since these errors tend to just break the execution of the test function and no assertions are therefor processed, this is a really dangerous thing to have in a testing framework. Any idea how to counter this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a helper you must add and it is described in integrating Velocity / Jasmine with iron router here in the Velocity docs:

https://velocity.readme.io/docs/jasmine-integration-tests-with-iron-router

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you may be hitting an async issue. `Router.go` is not instant, and you're checking too quickly right after to see if the current route has been switched.

Also, the `jasmine=true` is the URL for the mirror that gets hit to start the mirror testing, so when you get current route (too quickly) it's likely that will be returned. When you go to the mirror manually, it looks like the test is running again (because you have `jasmine=true`), which in turn is running `Router.go`

I can't tell exactly what you're trying to test, but you could add a hook to do your assertion in an `Router.onAfterAction`. Don't forget to also use Jasmine's `done()` method since you'll be doing an Async test.

As for the tests running green on exceptions, that would be a bug! If you could create a reproducible repo and post a bug on the framework's issues on GitHub, it will help get that resolved.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It turns out that it was indeed a problem with the apparently async nature of Router.go. (It doesn't even have a callback, which makes it quite frustrating to fix because the only way out is a timeout.)

I'm getting ready to file at least two bugs for Velocity as a few of these things seem unrelated to Jasmine or Mocha :(

Comment: From me, that's a :) because it will help get those bugs sorted!

Comment: You could also get creative with  Meteor.setTimeout() and test after some delay.  I would imagine you should also lobby Iron Router to include callback versions of the Router.go() functionality.

Comment: i've seen there is a post relating to this in the meteor-jasmine wiki : https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine/wiki/Integration-Tests-for-Iron-Router